# Stackoverflow exception automapper

Tags: c#, exception, automapper, stack-overflow, circular-reference

So a little insight into my problem, i have 4 classes employee, employeedto, request and requestdto as shown below, they have circular references, i have created mapping configuration for them but when i try to map list of employees to employeedtos i get stackoverflow exception even though i am using MaxDepth(1).

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RequestDto> RequestsDto { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public EmployeeDto CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>().MaxDepth(1)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
    {
        dest.RequestsDto = context.Mapper.Map<List<RequestDto>>(src.Requests);
    });

cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>().MaxDepth(1)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
    {
        dest.Requests = context.Mapper.Map<List<Request>>(src.RequestsDto);
    });

cfg.CreateMap<Request, RequestDto>().MaxDepth(1)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
    {
        dest.CreatedBy = context.Mapper.Map<EmployeeDto>(src.CreatedBy);
    });

cfg.CreateMap<RequestDto, Request>().MaxDepth(1)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .AfterMap((src, dest, context) =>
    {
        dest.CreatedBy = context.Mapper.Map<Employee>(src.CreatedBy);
    });
```

The exception occurs on this line when i try to map employees to employedtos.

```
var mapped = _mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDto>>(employees);
```

Comment: `RequestDto` is a member of `EmployeeDto` and `RequestDto` also has an `EmployeeDto` member. I don't think that is what you intended with your class design.

Comment: @Crowcoder A many-to-one relationship is pretty standard. An Employee owns many Requests and each Request is owned by a single Employee.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks, exactly my point, the design is not the issue here.

Comment: I see. Apologies. However, when your use of Automapper is more complex than just writing the conversion you get diminishing returns. Are your classes really this simple or is this code just for basic example?

Comment: Thanks for the question, i forgot to mention that this is just simple example of what i am trying to do, but the idea is same.

Comment: Replace AfterMap with MapFrom. Only when the names don't match. Remove MaxDepth. Don't call Map explicitly.